# Incorrect Typescript imports in VSCode for MacOS

Tags: visual-studio-code, auto-import

In VSCode, auto imports are not correct on MacOS.

This is what I see when referring to an unimported module in VSCode.

[image: pop up by vs code]

However, the file path is incorrect. This path assumes that the file is located at the root of the project which is not true.

This is how the import from constants folder needs to be, and this is what VSCode adds:

[image: incorrectly imported module]

According to my friend, this works perfectly on Ubuntu. I haven't added any special marketplace packages that give this feature, AFAIK.

What could be the problem?

Comment: I'm having same issue

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue.
Go to **File > Preferences > settings** and type "Import Module Specifier" in the searchbox.

Then set the option **TypeScript › Preferences: Import Module Specifier** to **relative**:

[image]

Comment: Can we do this for JavaScript?

Comment: I would say yes. Just use the setting "JavaScript > Preferences: Import Module Specifier" and set it to "relative".